# How to maintain ssh-agent login session with Windows 10's new OpenSSH and PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, ssh, powershell, openssh, windows-10-v1803

On my Ubuntu machine, I simply use Keychain to maintain a single ssh-agent which stays logged in.

I'd like something similar to that on Windows now that OpenSSH is natively included. I was using Git Bash with the well-known `if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] ; then ...` script but this resulted in many ssh agents being opened, I knew it was advised against (partly due to this blog post: http://rabexc.org/posts/pitfalls-of-ssh-agents) - which is what made me get Keychain for Ubuntu. Another reason for not using this any more is that I'm moving to PowerShell as my main shell.

But I'm not sure how to achieve the same kind of thing on Windows specifically *with PowerShell* and *with Win32-OpenSSH*.

Thanks!

Comment: Related: for anyone landing on this page but looking for a solution for Git Bash instead of PowerShell, see this answer here instead: [Stack Overflow: Running SSH Agent when starting Git Bash on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18404557/4561887). I've added [an answer for that too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76568760/4561887).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You must configure OpenSSH Authentication Agent service to automatically start (or you can start it manually every time when opening your PowerShell for the first time: `Start-Service ssh-agent`).

After that, you need to `ssh-add C:\path\to\your\ssh\key\id_rsa` only once. After that, every time the ssh-agent is started, the key will be there. You can check with `ssh-add -l`.

To have SSH agent to automatically start with Windows, you can run:

```
Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Automatic
```

on a Administrator PowerShell prompt.

Comment: Could you please add details on how to get ssh-agent to start automatically?

Comment: @MarkWoon I just edited my answer with that.

Comment: This does not seem to work -- the Set-Service has no apparent effect, and the manual Start-Service, while it starts something, is also ineffective -- any ssh-add command thereafter fails with "communication with agent failed"...

Comment: * In the startmenu search for "Services"
* Double click on "OpenSSH Authentication Agent"
* Set the startup type to "Automatic"
* Click "Start"
* Click Ok and Exit
* 
* Now go to PowerShell and add your key with "ssh-add"
* After that the agent will remember your key when you need it :)

Comment: The agent doesn't remember my key just added. `ssh-add` followed by `ssh-agent -l` shows nothing.

Comment: Starting the service manually didn't work for me, got "Cannot start service ssh-agent on computer" @EsbenAndersen's suggestion to use Services worked for me. The OpenSSH Authentication Agent service was set to Disabled by default, likely why Powershell couldn't start it.

Comment: @EsbenAndersen Thanks for the tip, I was wondering why there wasn't "SSH Agent" or something like this in Services.

Comment: You have to start PowerShell as an admin to run that command. Do that by pressing Windows key --> search for "powershell" --> right-click it and choose "Run as administrator." Then you can run `Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Automatic` inside it.

Comment: These instructions alone didn't work for me. I found another way to be more effective, and [added an answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1792045/425838).

Answer (score 4):

Not a full answer, but still a solution to the problem that brought me here. (I also see a comment from one other person here that seems to be the same problem.)

If you have Git for Windows or MinGW or anything else which might add GNU utilities to your Windows path, that can interfere with the OpenSSH for Windows binaries. For me, I had to remove ProgramFiles/Git/bin from my PATH environment variable and then restart PowerShell in order to get this to work. Prior to that I was getting "communication with agent failed"

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what's covered here, I ran into an issue getting it to work with Git because apparently Git uses its own SSH executable by default. To solve this, you need to set `core.sshCommand` in your Git config to point to the OpenSSH executable installed by Windows:

```
git config --global core.sshCommand C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe
```

This article is where I found the solution, and it covers all the steps of the process of setting up SSH in Windows: https://richardballard.co.uk/ssh-keys-on-windows-10/.

Answer (score 2):

> I knew it was advised against (partly due to this blog post: http://rabexc.org/posts/pitfalls-of-ssh-agents) - which is what made me get Keychain for Ubuntu.

In light of this argument I must warn you **against** using ssh-agent from the PowerShell port of openssh as it silently uses ondisk storage of your keys in the Registry. See my own question (and answer) [where-does-windows-openssh-ssh-agent-service-secretly-store-private-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65629402/where-does-windows-openssh-ssh-agent-service-secretly-store-private-keys) for a full explanation.

Essentially there are 3 problems with it:

1. It stores secret keys ON DISK - never use in a shared or guest situation
2. (traces of) Secret keys remain ON DISK after deletion
3. PoweShell implementation does not conform to the openssh manual page ssh-agent.1 in key aspects of security.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score -1):

Searching for solutions to keep the `ssh-agent` open while using **Git Bash (part of Git for Windows)**, rather than Windows PowerShell, may land you here too. Here's how to do that instead:

The best Windows instructions I've ever seen are on GitHub's documentation website, here: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases?platform=windows#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows

Essentially, you just need to add this script to the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file on Windows (usually at `/c/Users/myusername/.bashrc`):

```bash
# -------------------------------- START -----------------------------------
# Auto-launch the ssh-agent and load all private keys on Git for Windows
# Copied from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76568760/4561887
env=~/.ssh/agent.env

agent_load_env () { test -f "$env" && . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

agent_start () {
    (umask 077; ssh-agent >| "$env")
    . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

agent_load_env

# agent_run_state: 0=agent running w/ key; 1=agent w/o key; 2=agent not
# running
agent_run_state=$(ssh-add -l >| /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?)

if [ ! "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] || [ $agent_run_state = 2 ]; then
    echo "Starting ssh-agent and adding your private keys."
    agent_start
    ssh-add
elif [ "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && [ $agent_run_state = 1 ]; then
    echo "Adding your private keys to ssh-agent."
    ssh-add
fi

unset env
# -------------------------------- END -------------------------------------
```

I provide full, beginner-friendly instructions in my answer here: [Stack Overflow: Running SSH Agent when starting Git Bash on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76568760/4561887)

Comment: The question is about Windows' SSH client and PowerShell. Your answer is about Git Bash.

Comment: @DaviKoscianskiVidal, thanks for the feedback. I've made note of that in my opening sentence in this answer now. I didn't realize the difference and my mistake before.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to start the OpenSSH Authentication Agent service every time your device boots, but only when you open a shell, then consider adding the command to start the service to your PowerShell profile.

First, open the profile with your favorite editor:

```
notepad $PROFILE
```

Then paste the following code:

```
# For OpenSSH Authentication Agent startup and shutdown
$IsAdmin = ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")
if ($IsAdmin)
{
    $ServiceName = "ssh-agent"
    ($ServiceObject = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName) | Set-Service -StartupType Manual
    if ($ServiceObject.Status -ne "Running")
    {
        Start-Service $ServiceName
    }
    Write-Host "You can use git with SSH in this shell"
    Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier PowerShell.Exiting -Action {
        taskkill /F /IM ssh-agent.exe /T
    }
}
else {
    Write-Warning "You cannot use git with SSH in this shell because it was not launched with admin privileges"
}
```